# How to Optimize "JOIN" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables to pull information from `user: first_name`, `mongouser: email, card_status`,`transaction: transaction_type, balance, posted_at, is_atm, is_purchase`, `user_login: user_id, login_date, login_id`...

Before I added the fourth table - `user_login`, everything was efficient. However, the fourth JOIN made everything slow. I wrote queries as shown below

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT
ssluserid,
first_name,
m.email,
zipcode,
date_part('year',age(birthday)) AS birthday,
(current_date - DATE(created_date)) AS duration,
CASE WHEN card_status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_ACTIVE,
SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Credit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN balance END) AS LOAD_AMT,
SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Debit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN balance END) AS SPEND_AMT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Credit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN balance END) AS LOAD_CT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Debit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN balance END) AS SPEND_CT,
MIN(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Credit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN DATE(posted_at) END) AS FIRST_LOAD,
MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Credit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN DATE(posted_at) END) AS LAST_LOAD,
MIN(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Debit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN DATE(posted_at) END) AS FIRST_SPEND,
MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Debit' AND balance > 1.00 THEN DATE(posted_at) END) AS LAST_SPEND,
  SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Debit' AND is_atm = 't' AND DATE(posted_at) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '90 days'
                                    THEN balance END) AS ATM_AMT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Debit' AND is_purchase = 't' AND DATE(posted_at) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '90 days'
                                    THEN balance END) AS POS_AMT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Credit' AND balance > 1.00 AND DATE(posted_at) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '90 days' 
                                    THEN balance END) AS LOAD_VOL,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(login_date) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '90 days' THEN 
login_id END) AS CT_LOGIN
FROM
mongouser m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
user u
ON m.userid = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t
ON u.id = t.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_login l
ON m.userid = l.user_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7) t
WHERE LAST_LOAD >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '90 days'
ORDER BY 9 DESC;
```

This query has been running for almost 40 min...Are there any ways to optimize it?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of ways to optimise it.  You could use EXPLAIN to get a report on where the big costs are in your query and determine if there are any places that would benefit from better use of indexes, you could alter the table's indexes, you could limit the number of columns you fetch or the number of rows your fetch, etc.  Or you could try removing the Debit/Credit flag and having debits stored as negative amounts, then you could eliminate all that CASE stuff.  Have you tried to find any optimisations yourself or at least research where your query is being held up?

Comment: @GordonM thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing on just your statements you know where the problem is. You had this before

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u
ON m.userid = u.id
```

And you say things "weren't slow." Then you add this,

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_login l
ON m.userid = l.user_id
```

And you say things get slow. It's likely that you have an index on `m.userid`. Do you have an index on `l.user_id`?

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON user_login ( user_id );
```

Comment: you are right. the userid in mongouser table doesn't have an index on it while the user_id in user_login table has an index. However could you please explain more why adding user_login table could make everything slow down? it was 22 seconds before adding this table in.

Comment: 22 seconds is already slow. I have no idea of the user, but if you don't have an index you have to run through ever table and join them in a nested loop (if ordered), or join them in a bitmap join. Both are slow.

Comment: Are there ways to optimize this query except for creating index? Sadly, as an analyst, i have no permission creating index on tables...

Comment: No. Ask for permission.